# Conectar godaddy con Filezilla

Tags: filezilla

tengo un problema para conectar mi cuenta de godaddy con Filezilla, los datos con los que cuento son

1. 360estudiomx.com
2. Usuario de inicio de sesion
3. Contraseña de inicio de sesion

y Filezilla me pide lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

segun yo ya puse todo correcto pero no me conecta, espero y me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: ya probaste con el puerto 21 ? es el usado por los FTP

Comment: ya lo hise y nada